# Modify image from file and save

Tags: android, image-processing, bitmap

I need to load image from file to ImageView draw something on it and save to the same file. All of mine modifications are drawn in separate view called `mCanvasView`. Here is my saving code:

```
    private void saveResult() {
    OutputStream stream = null;
    try {
        Bitmap result;
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
            BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            options.inMutable = true;
            result = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(mFilePath, options);
        } else {
            Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(mFilePath);
            result = bitmap.copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, true);
            bitmap.recycle();
        }
        float resultWidth = result.getWidth();
        float resultHeight = result.getHeight();
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(result);
        Bitmap overlay = mCanvasView.getDrawingCache();
        Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
        matrix.setScale(resultWidth / overlay.getWidth(), resultHeight
                / overlay.getHeight());
        canvas.drawBitmap(overlay, matrix, new Paint());
        stream = new FileOutputStream(mFilePath);
        result.compress(CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        leaveActivityWithMissingData();
    } finally {
        IOUtils.closeQuietly(stream);
    }
}
```

First of all - it's really slow. I don't understand why. Secondly, if image shot in portrait mode then saved image will be rotated. Why? I don't apply any rotation.

I've modified my code like this to use rotation data from EXIF:

```
    OutputStream stream = null;
    try {
        Bitmap original;
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
            BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            options.inMutable = true;
            original = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(mFilePath, options);
        } else {
            Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(mFilePath);
            original = bitmap.copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, true);
            bitmap.recycle();
        }
        int resultWidth = original.getWidth();
        int resultHeight = original.getHeight();
        int rotation = Utils.getRotation(mFilePath);
        if (rotation % 180 != 0) {
            resultHeight = original.getWidth();
            resultWidth = original.getHeight();
        }
        Bitmap result = Bitmap.createBitmap(resultWidth, resultHeight,
                Config.ARGB_8888);
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(result);
        Matrix rotationMatrix = new Matrix();
        rotationMatrix.setRotate(rotation, resultWidth / 2,
                resultHeight / 2);
        canvas.drawBitmap(original, rotationMatrix, new Paint());
        original.recycle();
        Bitmap overlay = mCanvasView.getDrawingCache();
        Matrix scaleMatrix = new Matrix();
        scaleMatrix.setScale(resultWidth / overlay.getWidth(), resultHeight
                / overlay.getHeight());
        canvas.drawBitmap(overlay, scaleMatrix, new Paint());
        overlay.recycle();

        stream = new FileOutputStream(mFilePath);
        result.compress(CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
        result.recycle();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        leaveActivityWithMissingData();
    } finally {
        IOUtils.closeQuietly(stream);
    }
```

But this leads to OOM on every call. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: check this out for the orientation of the photo http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16949001/photo-picker-portrait-turns-to-landscape/16949619#16949619

Comment: No real comment on performance, but you may want to check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4374141

Answer (score 0):

Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4374141) may help to understand performance problem. 
Also, don't forget to close your `stream` after finished compressing.

As for rotation - may be your camera sets original preview mode with `setDisplayOrientation(90)` or similar ? Then you could always rotate to match image to preview by applying `matrix.postRotate(90);`

Comment: I'm using default camera via intent.

Comment: @Lingviston This http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14066038 explains how to get info about occurred rotation, using this info you can then rotate your image appropriately

Comment: It looks like all this transformations are rather memory comsuming opertaion. I can't understand they make such a simple operation so difficult. There is no way to "draw" my overlay directly to file with initial image?

Comment: First, are you sure that your file with initial image contains properly oriented image ? Secondly, I would recommend capturing the bitmap, rotating it if needed according to the link above, applying your overlay and then saving it to file

Comment: Capturing and editing are separate actions. They are done via different parts of app.

Comment: @Lingviston Anyway, does orientation of your saved image matches your preview (or your expectations) ?

Comment: before aditing if firstly load image to ImageView (but using third-party library) and it has the same orientation I've captured it.